# SQLite callback causes recursive exceptions after a successful return

Tags: delphi, sqlite

I am developing this Delhi 2009 app with SQLite database version 3.7.9, accessed by the Zeos components.  Started off OK - I can create a DB if none exists, create tables and insert records - the 'normal stuff'. There is a little table that contains serial params for a connection to some old equipments and the serial comms handler needs to be informed of connection parameter changes, but the Zeos components do not support events on SQLite.

I looked at the SQLite API and there is a 'Data change notification callback', so I set about making this happen.  The setup prototype is:

```
void *sqlite3_update_hook(
  sqlite3*, 
  void(*)(void *,int ,char const *,char const *,sqlite3_int64),
  void*
);
```

So, in Delphi, I imported the DLL call:

```
function sqlite3_update_hook(pDB:pointer;pCallback:pointer;aux:pointer): pointer; stdcall;
..
function sqlite3_update_hook; external 'sqlite3.dll' name 'sqlite3_update_hook';
```

..and declared an empty callback for testing:

```
function DBcallback(aux:pointer;CBtype:integer;CBdatabaseName:PChar;CBtableName:PChar;CBrowID:Int64):pointer; stdcall;
begin

end;
```

..and called the setup:

```
sqlite3_update_hook(SQLiteHandle,@DBcallback,dmOilmon);
```

`SQLiteHandle` is the `sqlite3*` pointer for the database as retrieved from the driver after connection. `dmOilmon` is the DataModule instance so that, when working correctly, I can call some method from the callback, (yes, I know callback is in an unknown thread - I can deal with that OK, I'll just be signaling semaphores).

Good news: when I ran the app, the `DBcallback` was called, aparrently successfully, upon the first insert.  Bad news: some little time later, the app blew up with 'Too many exceptions', and usually a CPU window full of '??', (the occasional alternative was system death and a reboot - Vista Ultimate 64).  Breaking in the callback, aux, `CBtype` and `CBrowID` were all as expected but the debugger tooltip showed the `CBdatabaseName` / `CBtableName` `PChars` to be pointing at a string of Chinese characters..

I tried to trace where the callback is called from - the call chain passes through in the Zeos driver code, for some reason.  Breaking there and stepping through, I checked the stack pointer and it's the same before and after the callback.

So, I set up the 'empty' callback, the callback gets called at the expected point but with a coupe of dodgy-looking parameters, the callback returns to whence it came with the SP correct.  I seem to have done everything right, but... :((

Has anyone seen this, (or fixed it even:)?

Can you suggest a mechanism whereby an aparrently successful callback can pesuade an app to later generate recursive exceptions?

Does anyone have any suggestions for further debugging?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Have you tried changing CBdatabaseName and CBtableName callback function parameters to PAnsiChar? IIRC SQLite expects ansichars here.

Comment: I'll try that now.  Update - I just tried running the EXE outside the debugger - it was stopped by the OS with a DEP box!  Looks just like a return address being corrupted, but where?

Comment: @Linas - OK, yes, thanks, that's the Chinese gone.  Using PAnsiChar and the debugger now shows the correct values for the CBdatabaseName and CBtableName.

Comment: Glad it fixed the problem. Note that Zeos doesn't support unicode in SQLite, to make it work you need to do heavy workarounds. You could use my wrapper (http://code.google.com/p/sv-utils/wiki/Intro), it supports SQLite3 update hooks.

Comment: @Linas - well, it fixed the problem that two parameters looked wrong - I can now be more sure that the callback is being fired correctly.  Now I just have to fix the crash afterwards..  :((

Comment: @Linas - and I will look at your wrappers too!

Comment: @Linas - unit SQLiteTable3 implementation uses Rtti - no Rtti unit in D2009 :(

Comment: I think I can try to make it compatible with Delphi 2009. Rtti stuff is used only for custom data mapping. I can add some ifdefs to make it work only in newer Delphi version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the problems with correct translation of SQLite header to Delphi and with linking:

1. Not `stdcall`, but must be `cdecl`.
2. Your `function DBcallback` must be a `procedure`. Because `void(*)(...)` is a pointer to C function returning `void`.
3. Not `PChar`, but must be `PAnsiChar`. For non-Unicode Delphi's it may be not important, for Unicode Delphi's, it is only a correct translation.
4. You are using compile-time dynamic linking (`external 'sqlite3.dll' ...`) to sqlite3.dll. But ZeosLib uses run-time dynamic linking (`LoadLibrary` & `GetProcAddress`). That may lead to "DLL hell" issue, when your EXE loads one sqlite3.dll, and ZeosLib plans to load another sqlite3.dll.

Comment: Thanks!  I found out about the cdecl when I moved the 'sqlite3_update_hook' setup call to a little procedure of its own and called the procedure - the return blew up.  Changing to cdecl allowed the procedure to run OK, so I changed the callback to cdecl as well.  It seems that it does not matter whether the callback is declared a Delphi function or proc - does not change the symptoms.